# neo4j filter results where date is in range of several periods

Tags: date, graph, neo4j, cypher, filtering

I need to filter visitors by dates, so I use this query

```
match (v:Visitor)

where datetime('2020-01-01T09:00:00.000000+13:00') <= v.at < datetime('2020-01-01T19:00:00.000000+13:00')

return count(v)
```

That's pretty simple and straightforward.

Now I have another requirement, I need to filter visitors by a range of dates, something like:

```
match (v:Visitor)

where
datetime('2020-01-01T09:00:00.000000+13:00') <= v.at < datetime('2020-01-01T19:00:00.000000+13:00')
or
datetime('2020-01-02T09:00:00.000000+13:00') <= v.at < datetime('2020-01-02T19:00:00.000000+13:00')
or
datetime('2020-01-03T09:00:00.000000+13:00') <= v.at < datetime('2020-01-03T19:00:00.000000+13:00')

return count(v)
```

Even though this works, it is super slow compared to doing 3 different queries with different ranges.

Is there a way to do something like the above but without hurting performance?

NOTE: I have an index on :Visitor(at)

Comment: can you check if you have created the index properly or not . Because , the time taken should be almost same in the first and second cases if you have an index

Answer (score 0):

The Cypher planner is apparently not yet smart enough to use the index in (probably rare) situations like yours.

However, you can work around that by using [UNION](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/union/) to get the results of 3 subqueries (each of which uses the index), and then use the new [CALL {} subquery in neo4j 4.0](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/#query-call-subquery) to do post-UNION processing to sum the 3 subtotals to get the `total` count.

```
CALL {
  MATCH (v:Visitor)
  WHERE datetime('2020-01-01T09:00:00.000000+13:00') <= v.at < datetime('2020-01-01T19:00:00.000000+13:00')
  RETURN count(v) AS cnt
  UNION
  MATCH (v:Visitor)
  WHERE datetime('2020-01-02T09:00:00.000000+13:00') <= v.at < datetime('2020-01-02T19:00:00.000000+13:00')
  RETURN count(v) AS cnt
  UNION
  MATCH (v:Visitor)
  WHERE datetime('2020-01-03T09:00:00.000000+13:00') <= v.at < datetime('2020-01-03T19:00:00.000000+13:00')
  RETURN count(v) AS cnt
}
RETURN SUM(cnt) AS total
```